# How to access a disk snapshot from google cloud locally?

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud

I'm using k8s on google cloud and I'm trying to use google cloud's build-in snapshotting for backups, but I would also like to use them for retrieving a db to work with locally. I've come to the conclusion that I need to first create an image of the snapshot, then export that image to a bucket before downloading. Something like this:

```
    gcloud compute disks snapshot mydrive --snapshot-names=mydrive-snapshot
    gcloud compute images create mydrive-image --source-snapshot mydrive-snapshot
    gcloud compute images export --destination-uri gs://my-bucket/mydrive-image.tar.gz --image mydrive-image 
    gsutil cp gs://my-bucket/my-drive-image.tar.gz file://my-drive-image.tar.gz
    tar xvf my-drive-image.tar.gz
```

This gives me a file `disk.raw`. Not sure how to mount this locally though?

Are there any other simple solutions to this? I would be fine to use a native k8s workflow instead as long as its on the volume level and doesn't involve actually running anything in a pod.

Comment: The `.raw` format is a sector image of the persistent disk. Which operating system are you running? There are software tools that can read a raw image and display the contents. Most disk imaging tools support this on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just mount the GCS bucket locally in which you exported the disk data?

You can use [gcsfuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) for doing this.

1. Follow these [instructions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md) for installing Cloud Storage FUSE and its dependencies
2. Set up credentials for Cloud Storage FUSE (follow the above instructions to do this)
3. Create a directory (or use an already existing directory to mount the bucket)
4. Use Cloud Storage FUSE to mount the bucket (e.g. `my-bucket`).

   ```
   gcsfuse my-bucket /path/to/mount
   ```
5. Now you can see the content inside the bucket:

   ```
   ls /path/to/mount
   ```

Comment: Don't think mounting the bucket actually helps? I mean, the bucket still contains a disk.raw image. Mounting the bucket would just mitigate the `gsutil cp` command…

Comment: True! if there is a way to export the data residing the disk to the GCS bucket. This method would work!